# How to add event to calendar in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, calendar

I have just recently started development in Flutter. I need to add event to the calendar in my Flutter app. The response i get from the api service is as follows.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20200504T143144Z
DTSTART:20200504T083500
DTEND:20200504T093500
SUMMARY:long class
UID:176606c7-f8a1-4636-9c36-4663bb437a5d
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am not sure how I should proceed. I came across a package: https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar#-readme-tab- But it doesn't mention about the implementation. How can this be done?